# How to get guava's Splitter.split to not return an unmodifiable map

Tags: java, guava

Seems as if the Splitter.MapSplitter method returns an unmodifiablemap.  Is there no way to get this to not return an unmodifiablemap so I can add to that map later?  Or must I take the unmodifiable map and copy it into a regular map to add?

```
Map<String, String> testParametersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
testParametersMap = Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator(":").split(browser:chrome,browser-version:56,language:english);
testParametersMap.putIfAbsent("country", "US");
```

The last line throws an exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.putIfAbsent(Collections.java:1515)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Copy the result to an implementation of your choice

Guava's `Splitter` always return immutable collections, so you can't make it return something mutable. Instead you should copy its result to a mutable `Map` implementation.

```
Map<String, String> testParametersMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator(":").split("browser:chrome,browser-version:56,language:english"));
testParametersMap.putIfAbsent("country", "US");
```

Or, similarly to what you wrote, you should then use `putAll` instead of reassigning the variable:

```
Map<String,String> testParametersMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
testParametersMap.putAll(Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator(":").split("browser:chrome,browser-version:56,language:english"));
testParametersMap.putIfAbsent("country", "US");
```

You can use any implementation, like `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap` and others. As Xaerxess mentions in the comments, favor `LinkedHashMap` as it preserves the order or the elements, if that's any importance for you.

Comment: LinkedHashMap would be my choice as it preserves order, which is unusually rather important (but YMMV).

Comment: @Xaerxess Indeed. I updated the answer with that in mind.

Comment: Your second solution worked perfectly.  Actually, order didn't matter, so I kept HashMap, but will keep that in mind.